# Javascript chart display labels

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

I'm using `chart.js 1.0.2` to draw a chart like this

[image]

Here is my code:

```
var data = {
    labels: ["2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020"],
    datasets: [{
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
        strokeColor: "blue",
        data: [180, 390]
    }, {
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
        strokeColor: "green",
        data: [180, 210, 405, 980, 1200, 1550]
    }, ]
}
var options = {
    bezierCurve: false,
    scaleFontSize: 13,
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false
};

var chart = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
new Chart(chart).Line(data, options);
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wyox23ga/290/)

The code seems fine, but it has 3 issues.

1. The line should start with 2015 instead of 0 (If you compare the fiddle with the image above, you ll recognize). I tried `scaleStartValue` but it is not working.
2. There is a circle on every point. I don't want the circle. I tried with `pointStyle:line` but it is not working
3. I need to display the information for the 2 lines Budget and Depense at the bottom (as shown in the attached image). I didn't found anything related to this in the documentation

If already achieved this kind of things please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need : http://jsfiddle.net/ap25v5j1/

For your 3 points :

1. Use this :

`labels: ["0","2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020"],`

and add `null` in `data`

2. use `pointDot: false`, to remove circles
3. Add `labels` in your datasets :

> ```
> datasets: [{
>     label: "Budget",
>     fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
>     strokeColor: "#00f",
>     pointHighlightFill: "#000",
>     data: [180, 390]
>   }, {
>     label: "Depense",
>     fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
>     strokeColor: "#0f0",
>     data: [180, 210, 405, 980, 1200, 1550]
>   }, ]
> ```

Then add following in your `options` :

```
legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><div class=\"legendSpan\" style=\"border-color:<%=datasets[i].strokeColor%>;\"/></div><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
```

Then generate legend :

```
var chart = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var lineChart = new Chart(chart).Line(data, options);
var legend = lineChart.generateLegend();
$('#myDiv').html(legend); //jQuery
```

or

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = legend; //js
```

Where `#myDiv` is a div in your html below your chart

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

And you will need to style it :

```
.legendSpan {
  width: 40px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 2px red solid;
  display: inline-block; 
  margin: 5px;
}

.line-legend li{
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```js
var data = {
  labels: ["0", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "Budget",
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
    strokeColor: "#00f",
    pointHighlightFill: "#000",
    data: [null, 180, 390]
  }, {
    label: "Depense",
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
    strokeColor: "#0f0",
    data: [null, 180, 210, 405, 980, 1200, 1550]
  }, ]
}
var options = {
  pointDot: false,
  bezierCurve: false,
  scaleFontSize: 13,
  scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
  legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><div class=\"legendSpan\" style=\"border-color:<%=datasets[i].strokeColor%>;\"/></div><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
};

var chart = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var lineChart = new Chart(chart).Line(data, options);
var legend = lineChart.generateLegend();
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = legend;
```

```css
.legendSpan {
  width: 40px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 2px red solid;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
.line-legend li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.chartjs.org/assets/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="420" height="350"></canvas>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: In this fiddle it is not working. But in your fiddle, it is working

Comment: I have included jquery. U need to do that or instead of jquery statement.. `$('#mydiv`) use plain javascript

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much

Comment: use : `document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = legend;` instead of `$('#myDiv').html(legend);` if you dont want to use jquery

Comment: I'm using JQuery as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To start from 2015

```
var data = {
            labels : ["0","2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020"],
            datasets :
                [
                    {
                        fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
                        strokeColor : "blue",
                        data : [null,180, 390]
                    },
                    {
                        fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
                        strokeColor : "green",
                        data : [null,180, 210, 405, 980, 1200, 1550]
                    },
                ]
            }
```

Use pointDot:false in option to remove circle on every point

```
  var options = {

           pointDot: false
}
```

For show the label use

In html file

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="420" height="350"></canvas>
<div id="legend" class="chart-legend"></div>
```

In JS

```
var data = {
            labels : ["0","2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020"],
            datasets :
                [
                    {
                        fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
                        strokeColor : "blue",
                        data : [null,180, 390],
             label: "Budget"
                    },
                    {
                        fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
                        strokeColor : "green",
                        data : [null,180, 210, 405, 980, 1200, 1550],
             label: "Depences"
                    },
                ]
            }
    var options = {
                bezierCurve : false,
           pointDot: false,
                scaleFontSize: 13,
          tooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>%",
                scaleShowVerticalLines: false
    };

    var chart = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(chart).Line(data, options);

document.getElementById('legend').innerHTML = myChart.generateLegend();
```

Style in CSS

```
.chart-legend li span{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 4px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This is working. http://jsfiddle.net/wyox23ga/301/ and for the labels?

Answer (score 0):

Since 1 and 2 has already been answered may I ask why dont you use the newest 2.1.6 version?

It is better and easier to use

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/

For example the circle problem can be solved there by changing this

```
Chart.defaults.global.elements.point.pointStyle = 'line'
```

and most important the information is displayed automatically and described in the *Legend Configuration* topic e.g.

```
Chart.defaults.global.legend.position = 'bottom'
```

From what I remember in the 1.x versions you have to create the info yourself

Comment: The older version is already used throughout the application. I don't want to rewrite everything.